# Convert list of floats into buffer in Python?

Tags: python, list, floating-point, buffer

I am playing around with PortAudio and Python.

```
data = getData()
stream.write( data )
```

I want my stream to play sound data, that is represented in Float32 values. Therefore I use the following function:

```
def getData():
    data = []
    for i in range( 0, 1024 ):
        data.append( 0.25 * math.sin( math.radians( i ) ) )
    return data
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work because `stream.write` wants a buffer object to be passed in:

```
TypeError: argument 2 must be string or read-only buffer, not list
```

So my question is: How can I convert my list of floats in to a buffer object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import struct

def getData():
    data = []
    for i in range( 0, 1024 ):
        data.append( 0.25 * math.sin( math.radians( i ) ) )
    return struct.pack('f'*len(data), *data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the easiest way is to use the [struct module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#module-struct).  It is designed to convert from python objects to C-like "native" objects.

Answer (score 0):

Consider perhaps instead:

```
d = [0.25 * math.sin(math.radians(i)) for i in range(0, 1024)]
```

Perhaps you have to use a package like pickle to serialize the data first.

```
import pickle
f1 = open("test.dat", "wb")
pickle.dump(d, f1)
f1.close()
```

Then load it back in:

```
f2 = open("test.dat", "rb")
d2 = pickle.Unpickler(f2).load()
f2.close()


d2 == d
```

Returns True